# Estatística em Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gem

Estou com o seguinte problema, preciso que meu sistema gere alguns dados estatísticos a partir de um vetor, por exemplo:

```
vetor = [1, 5, 2, 1, 6, 30, 2, 7, 2, 80]
```

Preciso extrair alguns dados dele, como:

- Média
- Mediana
- Moda
- Minimo
- Máximo
- Desvio padrão

Utilizo [rails](/questions/tagged/rails) na versão 3.2.15.

Minha pergunta é a seguinte, vocês conhecem alguma gem que me auxilie nisso ou terei que fazer tudo a mão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a gem [descriptive-statistics](https://github.com/jtescher/descriptive-statistics), tem todas as estatísticas que você mencionou.

Comment: Pode colocar o nome da gema, para o caso de o link quebrar?

Comment: Certo @Eagorajose, adicionei o nome da gem. Valeu